# Combine two filter_complex in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there any way to combine two filter_complex in ffmpeg? For example I have two ffmpeg commands that use filter_complex for add black background to subtitle and make hardsub and another command to add a watermark logo to video. I want to add a background to the subtitle and add a logo to the video and make hardsub in one command. Is it possible?

This is the command to add a black background and make hardsub.

`ffmpeg -i xp.mp4 -filter_complex "subtitles=H1.ass:force_style='OutlineColour=&H80000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,MarginV=10'" output.mkv`

This is the command to add a logo to  a video.

`ffmpeg -i output.mkv -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=W-w-10:10 [out]"  -map "[out]" -map 0:a final.mkv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i xp.mp4 -logo.png -filter_complex "[0]subtitles=H1.ass:force_style='OutlineColour=&H80000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=0,MarginV=10'[0v];[0v][1:v]overlay=W-w-10:10 " -c:a copy final.mkv
```